# How can I set global field in method

Tags: object, generics, methods, arguments

I have some problem, so I have a few global fields in class, for each I want to do the same code but I don't want to repeat code - just use one method for that. And there I want to send these global fields in argument of this method and as second argument I want to send value for this field.

I tried with object, generic type but I don't know how to do that. Here is example:

```
private void setName(String _name) {
    if(isNull(_name)) {
        this.name = "";
    } else {
        this.name = _name.toString();
    }
}
```

And a few other methods use the same code but with other fields and argument and I want to do something like that:

```
private void setField(some_field, _value) {
    if(isNull(_value)) {
        this.some_field = "";
    } else {
        this.some_field = _value;
    }
}
```

Could someone help?

For example I have 2 global fields: 
String name, int age.

For them I need to use the same code (if) and I want do it in one method. In this case I have to use global field as argument and as second argument use correct value for this field so instead:

this.name = argument; 
this.age=argument;

use: globa_field_argument = argument;

Example: 
setField( this.name, "Test" ); 
setField( this.age, 5 );

Answer (score 0):

First off I would probably declare your global fields as 'public static'.
for example:

```
public static int myNumber = 10;
public static String myString = "foo";
```

Secondly you should have to pass your fields as an argument since you can access them inside the method itself.

When you redefine the fields anywhere in your code you will do this:

```
this.myNumber = newNumber;
this.myString = newString;
```

Comment: For example I have 2 global fields: String name, int age. For them I need to use the same code (if) and I want do it in one method. 
In this case I have to use global field as argument and as second argument use correct value for this field so instead:
this.name = argument;
this.age=argument;

use: globa_field_argument = argument;

Example:
setField( this.name, "Test" );
setField( this.age, 5 );